# Tensor product $A \otimes_{F} B$ of finitely generated algebras $A, B$ with no zero divisors over a field has no nilpotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, finite-fields

I am trying to prove that if $A, B$ are  two finitely generated algebras with no zero divisors over field $F$ of characteristic $0$, then $A \otimes_{F} B$ has no nilpotents. How to prove this? I only could understood why assumption that characteristic $0$ is important, because if we have $\text{char}~F = p$, then $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \otimes \mathbb{F}_{p^n} = \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ -- direct sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, where the tensor product $\otimes$ is taken over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. This direct sum obviously has nilpotent elements, so assumption of zero characteristic is nessesary.

Comment: Why do you think that a direct sum of fields has nilpotent elements? I don't see any.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, i made a mistake and sum of fields doesn't have nilpotent (if i calculated this tensor product over $\mathbb{F}_p$ correctly), so caharcteristic isn't important...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume that $A,B$ are fields since we have embedding of rings $A\otimes_FB\to K(A)\otimes_FK(B)$. Suppose that $F\subset E=F(x_1,\dots,x_n)\subset E(\alpha)=A$, $x_i$ transcendental over $F$, $\alpha$ algebraic over $E$. Then $A\otimes_FB=E(\alpha)\otimes_EE\otimes_FB\subset E(\alpha) \otimes_EB(x_1,\dots x_n)$ and the last ring is reduced since $\alpha$ is separable over $B(x_1,\dots x_n)$.

Comment: Why is $A\otimes_FB\to K(A)\otimes_FK(B)$ injective?

Comment: @KentaS:  $F$ is a field so $\otimes_F$ is exact in each variable (every $F$-module is flat).

Comment: @Acrobatic Sorry for rather stupid question, but what is $K(A)$?

Comment: @NeoFanatic The field of fractions of $A$.

Comment: @Acrobatic does anything change is characteristic isn't zero?Because i suppose this proof works for 0 characteristic...or i am wrong?

Comment: @NeoFanatic If $\operatorname{char}k\gt 0$, $\alpha$ may not be separable over $B(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. For example if $A=B=\mathbb{F}_p(t), F=\mathbb{F}_p(t^p), $ then $A\otimes_FB=A[x]/(x-t)^p$ and $(x-t)\neq 0$ is nilpotent.

Comment: @Acrobatic thanks, now i understood

Comment: @Acrobatic May I ask you to elaborate a little bit, why does $\alpha$ being separable over $B(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ imply tensor product is a reduced ring?

Comment: @GlebChili If $H$ is an algebraic closure of $B(x_i)$ and $f(X)=\prod(X-a_i), a_i\in H$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$, then $E(\alpha) \otimes_EH=H[X]/\prod (X-a_i)=\prod H[X]/(X-a_i)=\prod H$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem. We can embed $E(\alpha)\otimes_EB(x_i)$ into it. (So, strictly speaking, we used separability over $E$; sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: @Acrobatic Yes, now I see. Thanks!